# Difference in $interpolate between AngularJS 1.0 and 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interpolation, angular-filters

I'm writing a filter to format addresses in a single line. The object that will be passed into the filter has the format:

```
{
  Line1: "123 Main St.",
  Line2: "Apartment 2", // Optional
  City: "Chicago",
  State: "IL",
  Zip: "60623"
}
```

I have the following so far:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('address', function ($interpolate) {
    return function (input, template) {

      if (input === null || !angular.isDefined(input)) {
        return input;
      }

      // template is optional. If not provided, use the following    
      if(!template) {
        template = '{{Line1}}, {{Line2 ? Line2 + \', \' : \'\'}}{{City}} {{State}} {{Zip}}';
      }

      try {
        var parsedTemplate = $interpolate(template);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(parsedTemplate, template, input, e)
        return input;
      }

      // Compile the template in the context of the input object
      return parsedTemplate(input);
    };
  });
```

In Angular 1.2 this works fine. However, in Angular 1.0 it fails with the error `Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 6-6 [?] in expression [Line2 ? Line2 + ', ' : ''].` My thought is Angular 1.0 doesn't support the ternary operator `$interpolate`d expressions, but I couldn't find any documentation suggesting that support was added in Angular 1.2.

Is there a way to use the ternary operator in Angular 1.0, and if not how can I get around that restriction?

(Bonus points - where in the documentation does it mention this change, or which commit in the Angular git repo made the change?)

Comment: I think I found the commit on another StackOverflow post that added ternary operator in Angular 1.1.5 (commit [6798fec](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b))

Comment: An alternate to using the ternary operator is: `someCondition && DoTruthy || DoFalsey`

Comment: @Ian I believe that's the answer to the question; maybe you should write that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: According to **[the changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)**, the support for ternary operator was indeed added in **[version 1.1.5 triangle-squarification (2013-05-22)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#user-content-1.1.5)**: _"**$parse**: add support for ternary operators to parser ([6798fec4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b))"_ So, it's this commit: **[6798fec4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that before I upgraded to 1.1.5, my workaround to using a ternary operator in interpolated expressions was to use `&&` and `||` (like `someCondition && TruthyResult || FalseyResult`) to effectively get the same result. Here's how you'd apply it to your code:

```
template = '{{Line1}}, {{Line2 && (Line2 + \', \') || \'\'}}{{City}} {{State}} {{Zip}}';
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/f9n6r/

The only problem with this setup is if the the `TruthyResult` doesn't actually return something truthy, the `FalseyResult` will be returned (just the nature of using `&&` and `||` like this, compared to the ternary operator). In your code though, `(Line2 + \', \')` will never be falsey because of the `\', \'`, so it won't be a problem here. But in a more general case, it could be.