# Angular JS $interpolate query

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I newbie to Angular JS and way trying to understand directive functionality which is written as below

```
function mydirective($interpolate, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        mycontent: '=',
        myurls: '=',
        mydata: '@'
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div ng-bind-html="html"></div>',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$watch('mycontent', function (value) {
            var html = $interpolate(value)($scope);

            element.html(html);

            $compile(element.contents())($scope);
        });
 } 
}
}
```

I am not able to understand following from above.

1) What does this $interpolate(value)($scope) do ? what is this second argument $scope.

2) What is this $compile function doing ?

3)  div ng-bind-html="html" in template what does it do  ?

Comment: Have you read the functions documentation? [$interpolate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) and [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage)

Answer (score 0):

> What does this $interpolate(value)($scope) do?

Gets the literal value of the `value` variable

> what is this second argument $scope.

It provides the context for data-binding

```
it('should interpolate with undefined context', inject(
   function($interpolate) 
     {
     expect($interpolate("Hello, world!{{bloop}}")()).toBe("Hello, world!")
     }
  ));
```

> What is this $compile function doing?

It converts the string into Angular markup

> div ng-bind-html="html" in template what does it do?

It compiles the HTML string within `$scope.html` and adds it to the markup

[image: scope mapping]

**References**

- [AngularJS Guide: Scope Watch Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope/#scope-watch-depths)
- [AngularJS Source: interpolateSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/interpolateSpec.js#L57)
- [AngularJS Expression Security Internals](http://www.veracode.com/blog/2015/07/angularjs-expression-security-internals)
- [Difference in $interpolate between AngularJS 1.0 and 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512778/1113772)

Comment: Using "literal" can be really confusing to a beginning developer. Why not just say, "It evaluates a string such as '{{fruits}}' to 'banana apples pears' when scope.fruits = 'bananas apples pears'".

Comment: @WilliamNeely I thought about that, but decided against the words `evaluates` or `formats` since that presumes a programming background. A picture is worth a thousand words, so I've added one.